# Hash each word from file

Tags: c++, hash

There is a small section of code im having trouble with. I have a program set up so far so that it reads in words.txt and then will cout each word. While im cout-ing it I need a hash function that will only hash each word once via a quadratic collision scheme and allow me to store it in a table.

Comment: Having googled for Hash Quadratic Collision (the Wikipedia article is helpful), I could probably take a stab at it and get it right.  But then it wouldn't be fair for you to put your name at the top and turn it in as your own assignment.  If it's not homework, then just use an unordered_map and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard hashing function `std::hash` used by `std::unordered_map` is excellent. If you find you need something different you can certainly provide your own by writing one and providing it as the third template parameter to the `std::unordered_map` declaration.

Regardless, the following gives you an idea how simple this is when using unordered_map and the other facilities provided by the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // load map with our words and their counts
    unordered_map<string, unsigned int> strs;
    ifstream ifs("words.txt");
    string str;
    while (ifs >> str)
        ++strs[str];
    ifs.close();

    // output results (use a lambda if you're using C++11, which
    //  you likely are since we have unordered_map. I've provided
    //  this just to show how it is done prior to lambdas.
    struct print_entry
    {
        ostream& os;
        print_entry(ostream& os) : os(os) {};

        // called by for_each for each map value.
        typedef typename unordered_map<string, unsigned int>::value_type value_type;
        void operator ()(const value_type& val) const
        {
            os << val.first << " : " << val.second << endl;
        }
    };

    // walk map with for_each, printing each entry to cout
    for_each(strs.begin(), strs.end(), print_entry(cout));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard hashing function provided by std::unordered_map

Then all you need to do is read word add them to the map and increment the count (the value part of the map (while the word is the key part of the map)).